# By using java selenium how to write data in Excel sheet

Tags: java, selenium

How to write data in the excel sheet by using java selenium? , below code is for reading data from excel sheet
After reading data from excel sheet and executing in the website is fine but,
Need: After execution, I want to "WRITE" the status in the excel sheet.

In my library code: 1)how to write code for write data in excel sheet?

2)How to retrive numeric value from excel sheet

below is my code---------------------

```
package demo1;

public class Exceldriven
 
{

WebDriver driver;

@Test(dataProvider="website")

public void FAHT(String firstnametest, String lastnametest, String Email String Password) //throws Exception

    {   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
  
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.*****************.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='txtFirstName']")).sendKeys(firstnametest);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='txtLastName']")).sendKeys(lastnametest);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='txtEmailID']")).sendKeys(Email);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='txtPhone']")).sendKeys(Phonenumber);
        }

@DataProvider(name="website")

public Object[][] passdata() throws Exception 
{
    Exceldata c1=new Exceldata("D:\\New folder (2)\\Testdata1.xlsx");
    int rows=c1.getrowcount(0);
    Object[][] data=new Object[rows][3];
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        data[i][0]=c1.getdata(0,i,0);
        data[i][1]=c1.getdata(0,i,1);
        data[i][2]=c1.getdata(0,i,2);
        data[i][3]=c1.getdata(0,i,3);
    }

    return data; 
}

}
```

below is my library code----------------------

```
public class Exceldata
{

    XSSFWorkbook wb;
    XSSFSheet FAHT;

    public Exceldata(String excelpath) throws Exception
    {
        try 
        {
            File src=new File(excelpath);
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);   
            wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

public String getdata(int Sheetnumber,int row,int column)
{
    FAHT=wb.getSheetAt(Sheetnumber);
    String data= FAHT.getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue();
    return data;
}

public int getrowcount(int sheetIndex)
{
    
    int row = wb.getSheetAt(sheetIndex).getLastRowNum();
    row=row+1;
    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: At which line are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Two points I got stuck
In below my library code
1) in public string getdata method , i wrote  code for read data  , now I want after execution of my script need to write data in excel sheet with dynamic code in "below my library code" .

Comment: 2) I want to retrieve numeric data from excel sheet , this code I want in  "in below library code". Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Example on how to write in Row 0, Column 0:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 1000);
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("YourText");
        
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream  = new FileOutputStream(file);
workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(file));

fileInputStream.close();
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: In my library code , i written for reading and excuting in website , but i need two things here , 1) how to retrive numeric value from excel sheet

Comment: 2) In library code itself , after execution of script how to write status value in excel sheet.